# Prevent Camera Capture on Android handet

Tags: android

Is it possible to write an application to prevent the Android handset from storing the capture picture? My thoughts are
a. Hook onto native camera apps and monitor for camera capture (or events). Once there is a capture event, my application will be able to detect and maybe remove the capture picture
b. Continously monitor camera capture picture storage. Are there any known i/o api l can use to do this?
c. Prevent all writes to the OS. Possible?

Thanks for all the feedback in advance!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

No. If this were possible, it would be a security violation.