# How to catch an image capture event on Android?

Tags: android, events, image-capture

I am trying to find a way to listen to a built-in Camera application Capture event.
I want my application to be triggered each time a picture is taken.

Is it possible?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019391/prevent-camera-capture-on-android-handet)

that it is impossible...

If it is impossible then, maybe, there is another way to achieve it?
For example receive a new file event and check if the file is picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible means impossible. :)

*Unless* you were to modify the Android platform yourself to override some of these security features and provide custom images which you would then flash onto individual devices, but I imagine that's not what you're looking for...